# Select "Name" + ( ':__________') from table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have select :

```
select name from table
```

My answer is :

```
Alex
```

Is it possible somehow to get a response, `"Alex: __________"` on my select?

Answer (score 6):

Use string concatenation:

```sql
SELECT name || ': __________' FROM table
```

However, I would question whether this is really the job for an SQL query or whether you should be doing the formatting in whatever middle tier language is calling the database.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you want a fix length of the answer then you should use something like:

```sql
SELECT RPAD(name || ': ', 30,'_') from table
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **CONCAT** function

**`select CONCAT(name,': __________' ) from table`**

look this link how to use details :https://www.w3resource.com/oracle/character-functions/oracle-concat-function.php

Answer (score -2):

select EmployeeName + ':___________' from Employee

Comment: `+` is the addition operator in Oracle. It is not overloaded for string concatenation as that has its own `||` operator.

Comment: sorry i thought its related to sql server